# What is the best way to change from polling to events?

Tags: .net, wpf, events, polling, modbus

If you were to parse 300 bytes of raw data 20 times a second into a bunch of WPF control properties, what would your solution be?

More specifically, I have a Modbus-enabled PLC and I need to make a WPF HMI for controlling it. Modbus is a communications protocol which requires polling for data changes. In contrast, WPF and .NET Framework in general promote event-driven model, so pushing data 20 times a second directly into controls seems unnatural to me. Not only does Modbus lack means of reporting data changes but also it doesn't provide high level representation of bytes, and it's up to developer to properly dissect an array of unsigned shorts into something meaningful.

While parsing such data is no big deal for me, coming up with a proper conversion to a bunch of event-enabled DependencyProperties (data binding assumed) is challenging. I wouldn't like to have a lot of initialization code or temporary storage to monitor changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It won't be necessary to put your cyclically polled data into dependency properties. Such data properties will only be used as source of bindings, so it would be sufficient to have them in a class that implements [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged.aspx).

I would suggest to collect data of about 10 polling cycles and update the data properties no more than two times per second. You will certainly poll in a seperate thread, so you should make sure that you invoke the [PropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.propertychanged.aspx) event on the UI thread by [Dispatcher.BeginInvoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.begininvoke.aspx) like in the code below:

```
public class DataCollector : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private byte[] someData;

    public byte[] SomeData
    {
        get { return someData; }
        set
        {
            someData = value;

            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(PropertyChanged, this, new PropertyChangingEventArgs("SomeData"));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Using INotifyPropertyChanged is a good point, thx (need a method for retrieving the updated property though). But pre-collecting data or limiting update frequency would introduce a significant lag in the UI, i.e. when the user clicks on a valve to open it, its state changes must be reflected as quickly as possible for logging purposes and the UI responsiveness.

Comment: A detail about retrieving... I wouldn't like to make separate properties for all data points (there are several dozens of them after parsing).

Comment: For the first point, it should be no problem at all to update the UI 20 times per second. Second point, you could go ahead with a data class with all data points as members and use that as the type of your data property.